# In Ember check whether a component is passed an action and use it if it is

Tags: ember.js

Lets say I have a component named `advanced-input` that contains an input such as:

```
{{input type="text" value=value class="{{class}}" key-down="keyDownAction"}}
```

In the js for the component I want to fire an action if it is passed to the component, if it isnt then I want to take my own action:

```
actions: {
  keyDownAction: function() {
    if (checkForActionNamedMyAction) {
      this.sendAction('MyAction');
    }
    else {
      // Provide some default code
    }
  }
}
```

So if I were to specify

```
{{advanced-input MyAction="SendAlertToUser"}}
```

it will go into the if, but If I have

```
{{advanced-input}}
```

then it goes into the else? What do I need to check for?

Comment: Define the default action on the component, when you pass it as an attribute it overrides it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the answer is fairly easy

```
if (this.get('MyAction') {
  this.sendAction('MyAction');
}
else {
  // Provide some default code
}
```

worked perfectly.